# how to display characters like ä, ö, ü, ß, Ä, Ö, Ü,é in uitableview as a textlabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsstring

I have stored the name called **Désirée Allenspach** in sqlite DB as a varchar.When I read this into a `NSString` variable to display in `UITableView` as a `textlabel`

```
//cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

It is not dispalyed as it is supposed to be.

I want to display it as **Désirée Allenspach** only without adding any extra character. Please help me

[image]

Comment: I think that they must automatically shows as text

Comment: hi, if you solved this problem, then please shared your solution with me. i have a same problem.

Answer (score 1):

What encoding are you using to store it in the database, and what encoding are you using to read it back out? You don't say what the problem is exactly, but assuming it's that you have garbage characters where the accents are, it's almost certainly an encoding issue at the storage layer, not a problem with your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can display unicode characters using the unicode key for them

`[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\u221e"]];` sets the text for infinity.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) you can get the list of unicode strings.

Comment: thanks folks,problem got resolved by using Nsstring's stringWithUTF8String method while reading from the DB hence was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringWithCString` method to encode your `NSString` object in `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

```
    NSString* myString = [NSString  stringWithCString:[specialCharConatiningString fileSystemRepresentation] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    myLabel.text = myString;
```

Comment: I tried using stringWithCString method with encodings like NSISOLatin2StringEncoding, NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding, none of them are rendering the actual characters instead these encodings are adding á à for é